# Summation for a field related to another one.

Tags: text-processing, awk

How can I find the summation for a certain field that is related to another field by `awk`, consider below sample:

File:

```
boo,foo,VO,1000
boo,foo,VO,1000
bar,var,DT,1000
var,bar,VO,2000
```

in this sample, I need to collect the number of `$3` per `$4`, so the result would be:

```
VO,1000 2
DT,1000 1
VO,2000 1
```

were 1st and 2nd fields ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind reordering, the following should work

```
awk -F, '{print $3","$4}' <file name> | uniq -c
```

`uniq -c` counts the number of repetitions

For your input, the output is

> ```
>   2 VO,1000
>   1 DT,1000
>   1 VO,2000
> ```

Further editing can be achieved via 2nd awk if required

Comment: Nice. Don't even need awk for this: `cut -d, -f3,4 file | uniq -c`

Comment: What if I need to get the summation? if the `$3` is a numeric value?

Answer (score 1):

To do it all in awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=SUBSEP=","} 
    {count[$3,$4]++} 
    END {for (key in count) print key, count[key]}
' file
```

```
DT,1000 1
VO,1000 2
VO,2000 1
```